# How to send data to server using angular.tojson?

Tags: json, angularjs, rest

Well, i'm having some difficult to understand the use of `angular.toJson`. I completely understand that it changes to a json object...

But, how can i send this obj to the server ?
The server already gives a json obj when `'GET'`, but how use it to `'POST'` and others?

sorry, i'm new :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need to call `angular.toJson()` yourself when posting data to a server or retrieving data from the server using the [`$http` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

This is the default behaviour that Angular does for you.

From [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#default-transformations):

> Angular provides the following default transformations:
>
> Request transformations (`$httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest` and
>   `$http.defaults.transformRequest`):
>
> - If the data property of the request configuration object contains an
>     object, serialize it into JSON format.
>
> Response transformations
>   (`$httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse` and
>   `$http.defaults.transformResponse`):
>
> - If XSRF prefix is detected, strip it (see Security Considerations
>     section below).
> - If JSON response is detected, deserialize it using a
>     JSON parser.

Comment: But, what is the need of this property  ( angular.toJson() )then ?

Comment: It is what Angular uses under the covers to do this JSON conversion for you. It actually just calls [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), but stripping out properties starting with `$` for you. Check out the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L1088) for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can create factory in your app:

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

 app.factory('requestsFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {
        return {
            postData: function (data) {
                var url = // some url to send your data
                return $http.post(data, url);
            };
        };
    }];
```

And now, you can post your data from controllers:

```
app.controller('yourController', ['$scope', 'requestsFactory', function ($scope, requestsFactory) {
    ...
    requestFactory.postData(anyData).success(function (result) {
        // if server send any response    
    }
    ...
}]);
```

Also you can use `$http` for `GET`, `PUT`, `DELETE` requests. [Click here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for more information